# Oracle insert multiple rows in multiple tables with one insert query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a query where I want to insert multiple rows in 2 tables. But it is only inserting the first row in first table. Here are my attempts below:

My procedure:

```
 PROCEDURE NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY
(
    IN_CREATED_BY               IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_MODIFIED_BY                         IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_USERNAME                            IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
    L_USER_ID INTEGER;
    L_PRIVILEGE_ID INTEGER;
    L_HIERCHY_ID INTEGER;
    N_USER_ID  INTEGER := hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL;
BEGIN
    SELECT case 
         when exists( SELECT USER_ID FROM T_MT_USER WHERE USERNAME = IN_USERNAME )
         then 
              (SELECT USER_ID FROM T_MT_USER WHERE USERNAME = IN_USERNAME)
         else 0
       end  into L_USER_ID
      FROM dual;
      
    IF (L_USER_ID = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO T_MT_USER
        (USER_ID, ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_FLG, ACCOUNT_LOCKED_FLG, created_by, CREATED_TS, ACTIVE_FLG, end_effective_dt, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS, "password", password_expired, start_effective_dt, username) 
        VALUES
        (N_USER_ID, 0, 0, IN_CREATED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP, 1, NULL, IN_MODIFIED_BY, SYSTIMESTAMP, '$2a$10$3hoAeeVJ0AG.CQS2xX8rT.wUlt1rjoiYsHW0YflZEiQ5QYzG4HpYi', 0, SYSTIMESTAMP, IN_USERNAME);    -- for Synergy1!
        -- start inserting in privilege talbe 
        insert into T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE (privilege_id,user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS,  modified_by,MODIFIED_TS ) values (8001,N_USER_ID,  IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        insert into T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE (privilege_id,user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS,  modified_by,MODIFIED_TS ) values (8003,N_USER_ID,  IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        insert into T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE (privilege_id,user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS,  modified_by,MODIFIED_TS ) values (8004,N_USER_ID,  IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        insert into T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE (privilege_id,user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS,  modified_by,MODIFIED_TS ) values (8007,N_USER_ID,  IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        insert into T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE (privilege_id,user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS,  modified_by,MODIFIED_TS ) values (8010,N_USER_ID,  IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        -- start inserting in hierchy table
        insert into T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE (hier_node_id, user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS ) values (101, N_USER_ID, IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);
        insert into T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE (hier_node_id, user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS ) values (102, N_USER_ID, IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);    
        insert into T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE (hier_node_id, user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS ) values (103, N_USER_ID, IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);    
        insert into T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE (hier_node_id, user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS ) values (5626, N_USER_ID, IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);    
        insert into T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE (hier_node_id, user_id, created_by, CREATED_TS, modified_by, MODIFIED_TS ) values (6548, N_USER_ID, IN_CREATED_BY, sysdate, IN_MODIFIED_BY, sysdate);        
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        log_api.fatal(log_ctx,'Exception in NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY');
        RAISE;
END NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY;
```

Call to my procedure:

```
execute USER_DEMO.NEW_USER('sbappi', 'sbappi', 'sumon8');
```

I have tried `insert all` too but no luck.

Comment: Do you get an error from the procedure call?. According to the title, I removed other products' tags.

Comment: no, no error shown

Comment: where is `log_ctx` declared?

Comment: log_ctx log_api.context; in spec

Comment: Have you checked triggers ?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your exception handling. Is it possible to remove `EXCEPTION...` declaration temporarily? Could you please show us `log_api.fatal`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing if you are trying to test from sql developer, you can put dbms logger to get the insert count and where its failing. Hope this snippet helps.

```
PROCEDURE NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY(
    IN_CREATED_BY  IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_MODIFIED_BY IN VARCHAR2,
    IN_USERNAME    IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
  L_USER_ID      INTEGER;
  L_PRIVILEGE_ID INTEGER;
  L_HIERCHY_ID   INTEGER;
  N_USER_ID      INTEGER := hibernate_sequence.NEXTVAL;
  lv_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO L_USER_ID
  FROM T_MT_USER
  WHERE UPPER(USERNAME) = UPPER(IN_USERNAME);
  IF (L_USER_ID         = 0) THEN
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER
      (
        USER_ID,
        ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_FLG,
        ACCOUNT_LOCKED_FLG,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        ACTIVE_FLG,
        end_effective_dt,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS,
        "password",
        password_expired,
        start_effective_dt,
        username
      )
      VALUES
      (
        N_USER_ID,
        0,
        0,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        SYSTIMESTAMP,
        1,
        NULL,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        SYSTIMESTAMP,
        '$2a$10$3hoAeeVJ0AG.CQS2xX8rT.wUlt1rjoiYsHW0YflZEiQ5QYzG4HpYi',
        0,
        SYSTIMESTAMP,
        IN_USERNAME
      ); -- for Synergy1!
    lv_cnt:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER ');
    -- start inserting in privilege talbe
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE
      (
        privilege_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        8001,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE
      (
        privilege_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        8003,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE
      (
        privilege_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        8004,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE
      (
        privilege_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        8007,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE
      (
        privilege_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        8010,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_PRIVILEGE ');
    -- start inserting in hierchy table
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE
      (
        hier_node_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        101,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE
      (
        hier_node_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        102,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE
      (
        hier_node_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        103,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE
      (
        hier_node_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        5626,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE ');
    INSERT
    INTO T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE
      (
        hier_node_id,
        user_id,
        created_by,
        CREATED_TS,
        modified_by,
        MODIFIED_TS
      )
      VALUES
      (
        6548,
        N_USER_ID,
        IN_CREATED_BY,
        sysdate,
        IN_MODIFIED_BY,
        sysdate
      );
    lv_cnt:=lv_cnt+SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_cnt||' T_MT_USER_HIER_NODE ');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  log_api.fatal(log_ctx,'Exception in NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY');
  RAISE;
END NEW_USER_PRIVELEGE_HIERCHY;
```